# SQL Server still thinks that a database exists

Tags: sql-server

I ran into an odd problem. I tried to disable an old, unused login but when I clicked OK the server came back with the following error

> The database 'xyz' does not exist. Supply a valid database name.

The odd thing is that that database was detached years ago. Somewhere, SQL still has some reference to it. Where can I look and how can it be removed?

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that this user has that `xyz` database set as its default database that he used to connect to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that this login has the `xyz` database set as its default database that he used to connect to?

[image]

If so: change that default database to something else, when you disable the login.

Comment: That was it. When I looked at the Default database the selected value was blank because the database obviously could not be found. Thanks!